# android get height and width of text with angle

Tags: android, text, height, width, rotation

I have a custom textview that is capable of rotating the text inside.

Question:
 - Once rotated, I need to get the width and height of rotated text only (not the texview). Is this possible. I tried using Paint objects to measure text but it doesn't give me right answers since my text is rotated.

I am really out of ideas right now that's why I need help from you guys. Any idea will do.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be an easy way, but doing the math yourself is also pretty easy. If you know some trigonometry, and you should if you're a programmer, just calculate the height and width yourself.

Comment: yes, I know trigonometry(C+, that's my grade).. But where would I start? What are the values that I'm going to use. I can't rely on TextView dimensions. What I need are the dimensions of the rotated text inside. It would help if you point me to a right direction. Thanks a lot..

Comment: ahh, yes I think I know what you mean now :). Your answer really helps. Thanks a lot..